# When can 'ci' be used to mean 'it'

Tags: pronouns, particles

I know that 'ci' can mean 'us' and 'there', but it appears it can also mean 'it'. For example:

> ci penso su - I'll think about it

I've heard that it means kind of "it, in general" but I find the rules for it confusing. Are there any hard and fast rules? When and where can 'ci' be used in this way, e.g.

> ci leggo
>   ci parlo
>   ci dico
>   ci metto

Also, in the case when it can mean 'it', how could you say whether it means 'it' or 'us' in a phrase such as, for example:

> ci parliamo

Answer (score 27, accepted):

*Ci* is indeed a tricky italian word, has it has several different uses and I'm afraid there are no fast rules, as its meaning greatly dependends on the context.

I'll try to go through some of the most common uses

It can be

### direct personal pronoun

> Il professore ***ci*** ha visto copiare.

which corresponds to

> Il professore ha visto ***noi*** copiare
>
> *The professor saw **us** copying*

---

### indirect personal pronoun

> Il professore ***ci*** ha detto di non copiare

which corresponds to

> Il professore ha detto ***a noi*** di non copiare
>
> *The professor told **us** not to copy*

---

### reciprocal pronoun

> **Ci** vediamo spesso
>
> *We see **each other** often*

---

### adverb

> ***Ci*** sono stato

which corresponds to

> Sono stato ***lì***
>
> *I've been **there***

#### redundant use as adverb

> ***Ci*** sto proprio comodo ***qui***
>
> *I'm really comfortable **here***

---

### verb compounds

In some cases *ci* can be incorporated in a verb, some notable examples being: **esserci** (*to be there/here*), **volerci** (*to be needed/required*), and **metterci** (*take*).

> ***Ci sono***
> ***I'm here***

or

> ***C'è*** qualcuno?
> ***Is there** anybody?*

and

> ***Ci vuole*** una laurea per fare quel lavoro
>
> *A degree **is needed** to do that job*

and

> ***Ci si mette*** un'ora per tornare a casa
>
> ***It takes** an hour to get home*

---

And really, many many other uses, especially in combinations with verbs.

Comment: This is very useful in general, but it doesn't address the usage of 'ci' to mean 'it', such as with 'ci penso' and I believe, 'ci parlo'.

Comment: @Groky ‘Ci penso’ is in the same class as ‘ci metto‘; usually ‘ci parlo‘ is regional ‘incorrect‘ usage for ‘I talk to him/her‘.

Comment: @Groky Yes, it does: "ci penso" is equal to "penso a questo/quello", i.e., falls in the category of the indirect pronoun. "Ci parlo" is the same: "parlo a lui/lei". That indirect pronoun is a demonstrative one in the first case and a personal one in the second, but the idea is the same.

Comment: @martina: indirect pronoun? Sorry, I still don't follow. From what I understand 'ci' as an indirect pronoun means 'us'. You mean it changes its meaning according to the verb?

Comment: Indirect pronoun: when the pronoun is accompanied by a preposition. So, "ci penso" (penso A questo/quello) is "I think ABOUT this"; "ci parlo" (parlo A lui/lei oppure CON lui/lei) is "I talk TO him/her".

Comment: @Groky it means “ci” can be used in any grammatical case without variation

Comment: @martina Ahhhh! Yes, I think I may be *starting* to understand! Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 3):

If we had to read those examples as you listed them, verbatim, the only one that makes sense is the second one: **ci parlo?**

The other ones don't convey any meaning. If you take a look, all of them require Direct Objects, except *parlare* which in Italian requires an Indirect Object (parlare *a chi?*).

As far as I know there are no hard rules, except for those cases that you listed, but if I find something I'll make sure to edit my answer.

Comment: Actually some others make sense too. *Non ci leggo* (*I can't read*), *Ci metto 5 minuti* (*It takes me 5 minutes*)

Comment: @Groky, absolutely. The only one I cannot come up with a valid use for is *Ci dico*.

Comment: @GabrielePetronella Indeed, that's why I pointed out that I was taking the examples as they were presented. :)

Comment: oh ok, I missed it.

Comment: @GabrielePetronella No problem! :P

Comment: "Ci" in "Ci dico" means "a loro" `- E se poi ti chiedono chi ha ucciso il re? - E io ci dico che è stato il maggiordomo`

Comment: @mucio I'm not sure that's Standard Italian. I've heard people using it, but they were all from the same place. I think it's dialectal/regional use.