# Che cosa significa "ci" in questa frase?

Tags: word-meaning, grammar, particles

Sto guardando il documentario *First Team: Juventus* su Netflix e ad un certo punto Buffon dice:

> Ci sto arrivando serenamente

Ha detto male o "Ci" può anche significare "io"?

Mi dispiace per il mio italiano impreciso.

Grazie mille.

Comment: Benvenuto su Italian.SE!

Comment: That sentence is correct, but “ci” doesn't mean “io”. However it may have several different meanings, most of which are covered in an answer to this old question: https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/29/when-can-ci-be-used-to-mean-it

Comment: In questo caso “ci” è un avverbio di luogo: la frase va interpretata come *Sto arrivando là serenamente*.

Comment: La stessa espressione può essere utilizzata in senso figurato: "Ci sto arrivando" = "Sto arrivando _a questo_" = _"Sto capendo questa cosa"_

Comment: Qualcuno può scrivere una risposta? I commenti sono utili, ma le risposte sono meglio!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The particle *ci* was originally an adverb, but then it also became a pronoun.

The adverb has a peculiar usage: it can only precede the verb or it needs to be attached to it.

> ci vado = vado là
>   andandoci = andando là
>   vacci = va' là (imperative)

It is an *avverbio di luogo* denoting some place already mentioned or clear from the context. Not completely equivalent to *là* as the sentences above might suggest. Just like many similar adverbs it can also be used for time (a place in time) and of course in figurative sense, a typical case being *ci sono arrivato* meaning *I have understood the thing I was thinking about*, as mentioned in comments. It can be used “absolutely” for emphasis like in

*qui ci vuole un esempio*

meaning *here an example is needed* (you know, mathematicians are fond of self-references) and is pleonastic, but it cannot be omitted, in this sense. The typical usage is *c'è* or *ci sono*, that is, *there is* and *there are*; however the usage is not the same as *there* as shown by the example above.

Possibly Buffon was talking about his retirement from played football and said

> ci sto arrivando serenamente

that would mean “I'm serenely approaching retirement”; in any case, it means *I'm serenely arriving there* (where the place or moment in time should be clear from the context).

The pronoun *ci* can never mean *io*: it is used as oblique form for the second person plural *noi*:

> ci vogliamo bene

means *we love each other* (reflexive form). It's sometimes used as the oblique form of the third person singular: *ci do* for *gli do* (such usage is frequent in Sicily, but is not really grammatical).